# How can I call a __thiscall from C?

Tags: c, this

I'm writing something in C that will be running in the context of an application written in C++ and i would like to call some of the application's functions that use calling conventions unsupported by C. Is there any way I could do this? I'm willing to get my hands dirty with the inline assembler.

I have the prototype and address of the function I want to call, but I can't implement the prototype in C because it is a __thiscall. Would something like

```
__asm
{
    push ecx
    mov ecx, this
}
ThiscallFunction(...);
__asm
{
    pop ecx
}
```

work, given I use the same function prototype but a __stdcall for ThiscallFunction()?

Comment: Simplest way would be to write some `extern "C"` wrappers.

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example? To me it's not clear what specifically you mean by "_calling conventions unsupported by C_". -- Do you mean methods with an implicit `this`? If so, and if you cannot use a C wrapper, you need to find the mangled name of that function, a pointer to the object, and you can call it with that pointer as a first parameter. -- If you mean a static function, and if you cannot use a C wrapper, you need to find the mangled name of that function, and you can call it. -- "objdump" is a tool to reveal mangled names

Comment: @thebusybee I know the address, return type, calling convention, and parameters of a virtual function and would like to call it, however I do not have the source code for the function and I am working with C and not C++

Comment: How do you plan to link your call with the address? All other stuff could be handled with an appropriate prototype. -- Please [edit] your question to add such new information.

Comment: Where do you get the address?

Comment: A manually collected chain of pointers from module base to object to vTable

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution depends on the problem, but generally, you will need a header file specifying the interface towards the C code. This header file should be understandable for both the C and C++ parts.

E.g. (common C/C++ header file):

```
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void draw_shape(void *shape_handle, double scale);
...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Furthermore, it is necessary to make wrapper functions in the C++ code for C++ functions with a prototype that is incompatible with C (e.g. having a `std::string` parameter or being a class member function).

E.g. (C++ class member function wrapper implementation):

```
void draw_shape(void *shape_handle, double scale)
{
    static_cast<Shape *>(shape_handle)->draw(scale);
}
```